# GMock doesn't compile, virtual function with user type reference argument

Tags: c++, reference, virtual, googlemock

I am trying to mock an abstract class but I keep getting compiling errors from inside the GMock headers. I can't share the actual code, but is almost the same as bellow. The mocking was working fine, but I had to change the "DoStuff" function to take an object but reference. Since then it doesn't compile. The error is something like * GMock can't compare "Element" to long long *.

```
"C++ code"

using ::testing::NiceMock;

class Element{};

class Foo
{
   public:
       virtual void DoStuff(Element&) = 0;
};

class MockFoo : public Foo
{
   public:
       MockFoo() {};
       MOCK_METHOD1(DoStuff, void(Element&));

};

TEST(example, test)
{
   NiceMock<MockFoo> mf;
   Element element{};
   EXPECT_CALL(mf, DoStuff(element)).Times(1);

   mf.DoStuff(element);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [generic comparisons matchers](https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md#generic-comparison).

If you want to check exactly the same element is passed via `mf.DoStuff` to your mocked object - use `::testing::Ref` matcher:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mf, DoStuff(Ref(element)));
```

(Note: that Times(1) is default - so not really necessary).

If you like to check if passed objects has exactly the same value - define comparison operator for it - or use some proper matcher - like `::testing::Property` - like:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mf, DoStuff(AllOf(Property(&Example::getX, expectedXValue),
                              Property(&Example::getY, expectedYValue))));
```

I guess your exact problems are because your actual `Example` class is abstract and/or does not have `operator ==` - so default matcher `::testing::Eq` cannot be used.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I do not need the for the exact "Element", I need to test if the function is being called. But again thanks, I am going to try your suggestions.

Comment: You might use any matcher `testing::_` if that is all you need `EXPECT_CALL(mf, DoStuff(_));`

Comment: Thanks thats even better!